# How to prevent fake data posting

Tags: javascript, jquery, post

I've got a game with scoreboard, so when the user reaches the top of the table, he is asked to send a highscore. The game is written in pixi.js, so I'm using $.post to send a score, but anyone can see a variables and send a fake score :-(

How can I prevent this?

```
$.post( "inc/new-highscore.php", { name: $(".playername").val(), time: Math.floor(game.getFinalTime() / 1000) }, function() {
      $( ".highscore" ).load( "inc/highscore-table.php", function() {
          $(".highscore .pagination").customPaginate({
              itemsToPaginate : ".record"
          });
      } );
  });
```

Comment: This could be interesting for you too : http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/40015/how-do-i-protect-sending-scores-from-html5-games-to-my-server

Comment: thanks, I did not found it before :-) it's helpfull